# bulk update of gridview made of checkboxes column

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have gridview in which there are 36 columns and 500 rows of checkboxes and it is binded dynamic.I need to find most efficient way to
update my database.Please suggest.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_services" runat="server" CellPadding="3"  CssClass="grid"
                 GridLines="Both" DataKeyNames="ServicesId" 
            BackColor="White" AllowSorting="true"
         BorderColor="#006699" BorderStyle="solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
          ondatabound="OnGV_ServicesDataBound" 
          onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" EnableViewState="False" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableTheming="True" >
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Height="40px"/>
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Services"  DataField="Services" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#089de3" ItemStyle-Width="12%"> </asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category"  DataField="Category" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#089de3" ItemStyle-Width="12%" > </asp:BoundField>

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: the efficient way of doing is sending the Values as `UserDefined-Table-Type` , you didn;t gave much info about your backend.. so sending data as a Table will be efficient in my view

Answer (score 0):

Efficient way huh!
**Option 1:** Keep a button called 'Export into Excel' which will export all records into excel sheet and a filecontrol called 'Bulk Update' so if  a user needs to update any records he will download all records into excel, make changes to those records and upload that excel. It is useful for bulk update.

**Option 2:** Provide fecility to edit and update data in gridview itself .Check out [THIS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9f0ae2/gridview-edit-delete-and-update-in-Asp-Net/) link. It makes easy record updates fast.